# Prevent anchor tags from loading a view in an Angular application

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am using AngularJS and ZURB Foundation for my application.

Foundation provides a readymade accordion, which requires an `<a href="#panel1"></a>` and a `<div id="panel1" class="content"></div>` to work.

I've configured the Angular `$routeProvider` to `.when("/menu", {...}).otherwise(redirectTo: "/menu")`.

Angular causes the clicks on the `<a>` to load the `/menu` route because of the `href=#panel1`.

I've removed the `href` attributes from each `a` and I'm handling the opening and closing of these panels myself with the combination of `ng-click` and `ng-class`, but Foundation is giving these panels `display: none` for some reason.

Is there a solution/workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding `ng-click="$event.preventDefault();"` to the `<a>`s